# Android - make a loggfile and display as a TextView in WITH new lines for every "events"?

Tags: android, textview, newline, logfile

Hi im logging Name and numbers to a file in android,
and then i open the loggfile, and show in a TextView.
but i can't add the "newline" ( " \n " ) so it shows:

Name1 nr1
Name2 nr2
Name3 nr3
Name4 nr4

i only receive "a mess" in one long line...

i try the following:

.....

```
addNameAndNrToLogg(stringName, stringNr); //call ..
.....

//save the logging
public void addNameAndNrToLogg(String Name, String Nr) {
            String content = Name + " " + Nr + " " + "\\\n"  + " ";
            content = content.replace("\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                try {
                    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriteropenFileOutput("logg.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
                    outputStreamWriter.write(content.toString());
                    outputStreamWriter.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());              
                }

......

loggfil = getLogg(); //open the loggfile and save this to a string (just an ordinary open file...)
          TextView tv = new TextView(this);
          tv.setText(loggfil); // set content to loggfile 
          tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());//make it scrollable
          setContentView(tv); //display it..


.....
```

//i have also tried to add \n, \n, \\n and nothing set the "new-line"-trigger..

//do you have any ideas?? :-)

EDIT:
I just want to be more precise:
I have now and this don't work:(  :

```
....

public void addMatchToLogg(String Name, String Nr) {

String content = Name + " " + Nr + " " + System.getProperty("line.separator");

try {
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("logg.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
outputStreamWriter.write(content.toString());
outputStreamWriter.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());              
}
....

// then in a other activity i open the logfile and put it in a textView:

loggfil = getLogg();
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText(loggfil);

tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
setContentView(tv);

...
}
..

//then the getLogg():
public String getLogg() {
String loggBuffer = "emty logg";
try {
InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("logg.txt");
if ( inputStream != null ) {
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
String receiveString = "";
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                }
inputStream.close();
loggBuffer = stringBuilder.toString();
            }

        }
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
return loggBuffer;
        } catch (IOException e) {
Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
return loggBuffer;
        }
return loggBuffer;
    }
```

**the result:**
    **Name1 nr1 Name2 nr2 Name3 nr3 Name4 nr4**

and not:
**Name1 nr1
Name2 nr2
Name3 nr3
Name4 nr4**

in the XML i have:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/emty"
            android:textSize="21sp" 
            android:maxLines="5"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

NOTE: and when i pull out the logg.txt-file from the "emulator" it is "wrong"/noNewLine: **Name1 nr1 Name2 nr2 Name3 nr3 Name4 nr4**

---

edited just for test and "a comment" I tested this:
I tested to "force the strings value" with:

```
Name = "Event:"; 
Nr = "123";
```

and then:

```
String content = siteName + "_" + shortDate + "_" ; 
content = content + System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
//(yes I know i probably want to use stringbuilder, or is it a must here?..)
```

and then send it to the logg, 3 times, result:

> Event:_123_Event:_123_Event:*123*

and not:

Event:*123*

Event:*123*

Event:*123*

**_________** :-(

Comment: So the file itself has no new lines?

Comment: exactly :-(

" Name1 nr1 Name2 nr2 Name3 nr3 Name4 nr4 "

Comment: Is there any chance that your file will contain elements with space in it like
Name One nr1 Name Two nr2 Name Three nr3

?

Comment: WOW intresting it is:
testNAME 1 Nr 08 12:58:11 testNAME 2 Nr 08 12:59:16 ..

and not:
testNAME 1 Nr 08 12:58:11 
testNAME 2 Nr 08 12:59:16 
..

I tested to "force the strings value" with:
Name = "Event:";
Nr = "123";
and then:
String content = siteName + "_" + shortDate + "_" ;    content = content + System.getProperty("line.separator");

and then send it to the logg, 2 times, result:
Event:_123_Event:_123_Event:_123_
and not:
Event:_123_ "+new line"
Event:_123_ "+new line"
Event:_123_ "+new line"

Comment: note: is it possible to write the "logg" so that the "latest name" it first and not last?:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a large amount of testing I founded myself that
it is **wrong** to add the new line in the file like i did before:

```
String content = Name + " " + Nr + " " + System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

(and then save it to a file, and then read it..)

**the string and the file probably have a "2 different & unice line.separator" :-)**

**so my solution:**

```
String content = siteName + " " + shortDate + "//n" ; 
//the "//n" is just a "MARKER" for later..
content = content.replaceAll("  ", " "); //just for nice things up..
//and save to file...
.....

//then when the textview want to display this:
// after the file have revived using getLogg()
        loggfil = getLogg();
//then i look after the MARKER: "//n" and replace this..
        loggfil = loggfil.replaceAll("//n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));

          TextView tv = new TextView(this);
          tv.setText(loggfil);
          tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
          setContentView(tv);
```

result is:
in file:
Name1 Nr1//nName2 Nr2//nName3 Nr3//nName4 Nr4//n

in the "saved String loggfil" 
Name1 Nr1
Name2 Nr2
Name3 Nr3
Name4 Nr4

Im so GLAD, Finally!!! :-D

but, still:
 **is it possible to write the "logg" so that the "latest name" it first and not last?**
i use:

```
            try {
                    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("logg.txt", 
                            Context.MODE_APPEND));
                    outputStreamWriter.write(content.toString());
                    //outputStreamWriter.write("test", 0, 4);
                    outputStreamWriter.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());              
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String content = Name + " " + Nr + " " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + " ";
```